# Perform GM_xmlhttpRequest() from eval

Tags: greasemonkey

I have a little Greasemonkey script that communicates with a servlet on (my) server. The servlet is sending back JavaScript code, which I eval() in the onload handler of the `GM_xmlhttpRequest`.

So far, all is working fine. Now, I'd like to use send another `GM_xmlhttpRequest` from within that `eval()`ed code. and here I'm stuck. I do not see any error, but all `GM_*` functions appear not to be working from within the `eval(responsetext)`.

If I hard code the `GM_xmlhttpRequest` in the onload handler (no `eval()`), it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to work around this problem, you can call `GM_*` functions with `setTimeout` set to `0` from `eval`'ed code. Try something like:

```
function myFunction()
{
  GMXmlHttpRequest(...)
}

eval('setTimeout(myFunction, 0)');
```

A better solution is to extend `Function.prototype` with a function called `safeCall` that does this for you. Whenever you have any `eval`'ed code that will call into `GM_*` functions you'll need to have `safeCall` somewhere in that call chain.

Comment: thanks. what i was trying to archive was a some additional check to prevent people tampering with the data being send to my servlet. for this, i wanted an additional round trip sending an security token, but with out a trace for this in the gm script. 

as this is not working, i guess it is better to play open (having traces (in you myFunction() suggestion could make users nervous) and just have the GMXmlHttpRequest() plain in the script and just receive/send a security token.

thanks again for your answer

Comment: Why does `eval('setTimeout(myFunction, 0)');` work but `eval('setTimeout(function(){myFunction()}, 0)');` doesn't? I need to call `myFunction` with some params, how should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Greasemonkey (GM) is hosting the user script, which means that it can add functions and objects to the user script, when you call eval() the script runs unhosted (the vanilla JavaScript is running it) and you don't get the GM API inside of it.

Comment: thanks for your reply. good to know that i do not need to wast more time looking for a bug in my code. not that i like the answer ;). but i understand that there are security reasons for this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution. I have the similar problem, I don't want to put all my logic in user script, because if I change them, user need to update them by themselves. So what I want to do is separating the main logic from loading logic, the main logic will be loaded at beginning by the user script and eval them.

So I made a function "sendRequest", which is a wrapper of GM_xmlhttpRequest(), I need it anyway, because the method, server url and onError callback are always same for my application, so I just put them into my "sendRequest" function to make the xmlhttprequest simple.

In the main logic javascript code, which is loaded from server, there is no greasemonkey function call at all. If I want to for example communicate with server, I will call sendRequest instead. It works.

Comment: btw, jQuery.getScript() doesn't work in GM, I need read the javascript code and eval them by myself.