# greasemonkey: perform GM_xmlhttpRequest() from eval (follow up)

Tags: ajax, greasemonkey, cross-domain

How can you call `GM_xmlhttpRequest` inside of an `eval` where you are `eval`ing some complicated code, some of which calls `GM_xmlhttpRequest`.

This is a follow up to [Perform GM_xmlhttpRequest() from eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074236)

Here is some sample code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Test GM AJAX
// ==/UserScript==

console = unsafeWindow.console;
function fetch(msg) {
  console.log('fetching: '+msg);
  GM_xmlhttpRequest({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://google.com',
      onload: function(responseDetails) {
          console.log(msg);
      }   
  }); 
}

function complicated(arg1, arg2) {
  fetch(arg1 + arg2);
}
console.log('trying');
var code = 'complicated("Ya", "y!")';
function myEval(code) {
  eval(code);
  eval('setTimeout(function(){'+code+'},0)');
  eval('setTimeout(fetch,0)');
  eval('setTimeout(function(){console.log("here");fetch("cool")},0)');
  fetch("BOO");
}
myEval(code);
```

which outputs:

```
trying
fetching: Yay!
fetching: BOO
fetching: Yay!
fetching: 30
here
fetching: cool
BOO
30
```

So the only fetch that worked was the `setTimeout(fetch,0)` but I need to actually execute the `code` which includes come complicated code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you justify your reason for using `eval`? From experience I can tell there's an alternative about 99.7% of the time. "I have complicated code" is not a justification.

Comment: I'm building a plugin system, where all the plugins are little pieces of javascript stored on the server, and sent over to the client to be executed. Each plugin can call into the client library to do some actions. Is there a better way than `eval()` for plugin systems?

Comment: I guess that might fall into the other 0.3%.

Answer (score 1):

as I have the same problem, just months later and their seems no answer out there.

If you only want to run this code on one machine or in an developing environmetn as I do, you might consider changing the Greasmonkey Addon source:
There it is only two letters: "//"
in components / greasemonkey.js, line 47 ff

```
 if (stack.filename != null &&
      stack.filename != gmSvcFilename &&
      stack.filename.substr(0, 6) != "chrome") {
    GM_logError(new Error("Greasemonkey access violation: unsafeWindow " +
                "cannot call " + apiName + ". --> DISABED"));
    // return false;  OUT-COMMENT THIS LINE 
  }
```

But take care, as you mya get security problems with mal scripts.